# Alcove address characterization of weak order reference request

Tags: reference-request, coxeter-groups

Let $\Phi$ be the root system of type $A$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an alcove of the corresponding affine arrangement. The *address* (or *Shi coordinates*) of $\mathcal{A}$ is a function $k:\Phi^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying
$$k(\epsilon_i - \epsilon_j) < (\lambda, \epsilon_i - \epsilon_j) < k(\epsilon_i - \epsilon_j) + 1,$$
for all $\lambda \in \mathcal{A}$. (Here $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Let $\leq_R$ denote the right weak order on $\widetilde{A}_n$. For $w \in \widetilde{A}_n$, let $k_w$ denote the address of the alcove corresponding to $w$. Weak order is characterized by
$$u \leq_R v \iff |k_u| \leq |k_v| \text{ and } \text{sgn}(k_u) = \text{sgn}(k_v),$$
where the signs are regarded as equal whenever $k_u(\epsilon_i - \epsilon_j) = 0$.

I'm looking for a reference for this characterization.

One can prove this in general by applying Theorem 4.5 of Humphreys' *Reflection groups and Coxeter groups*. Also, connecting Theorem 4.1 of Shi's [On two presentations of the affine Weyl groups of classical types](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869399980006) with Theorem 5.3 of Bj$\ddot{\text{o}}$rner and Brenti's [Affine permutations of type A](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v3i2r18) works. Is there something more direct in the literature?